# activemq url starts with scp://

Tags: scp, activemq

I have inherited a system where the activemq address looks like this `scp://localhost:61616`

ActiveMQ itself only seems to be configured for `tcp`.  I can't find any reference to that protocol here: http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-connection-uris

Has anybody seen this before?

Comment: Is the `scp://localhost:61616` used as a connection string?

Comment: yeah - and works

Comment: Which version of ActiveMQ you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCP is not supported by default in ActiveMQ for the connection string (checked in 5.16.x, 5.15.x e 5.14.x), but there may be a few explanations for why that works:

1. The code is manipulating the URI to ignore the protocol definition. You can confirm this behaviour by replacing `scp` to anything else and checking if it still works.
2. There's a custom implementation of the protocol, as the ActiveMQ loads it's implementations [using reflection](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/activemq-5.16.0/activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/util/FactoryFinder.java#L88). If that'd be the case I'd glad to see what are your use cases for implementing communication over `scp`.

Comment: thanks - something else was ignoring the protocol.  but thanks for confirming that it doesn't exist